# JavaMail API: Maintain escape characters in mail content of type html

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, html-email

I have a requirement where I receive a user input in the form string like:

```
"Hi there,\r\n\r\nThe information is not visible in the page since you’ve adjusted the app.\r\n\r\ncan you please fix it?\r\n\r\nThanks,\r\n\r\nXYZ"
```

While it looks like this in UI:

```
Hi there,

The information is not visible in the page since you’ve adjusted the app.

can you please fix it?

Thanks,

XYZ
```

I need to parse the above string with `/r /n` send it over mail to someone else.

Now, while I print this in console, it prints just like it looks in UI, quite obviously.

But, when I try to put this string as a `java mail` content, i simply get everything in a single line when I check the received email.

The content type for mail is set to `text/html; charset=utf-8`. I also tried `pre-wrap` styling but didn't work.

```
private static String createEmailContent(String descp) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<style> div { white-space: pre-wrap;}</style><div>");
    sb.append(descp);
    sb.append("/<div>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

How can I beautify the content to look exactly as received?

Comment: Is that literal code? If so, does correcting `/<div>` to `</div>` work?
If not consider writing code to insert `<br/>` instead of `\r\n`.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is plain text content, just send it as text/plain instead of text/html.

If you **really** need to send it as text/html, you'll need to process the data and instead html line breaks <br> or wrap it all in <pre>.